# Jenkins pipeline script nunit cosole to publish junit report

Tags: .net, jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, nunit-console

In jenkins we are using Pipeline Script which has huge code. In that a bit code which I am trying to generate junit report and to publish it in jenkins.
I using first time trying to publish a junit report in jenkins. Not sure what are the things I need to show my report in jenkins.
When I click on `CONFIGURE->PIPELINE` tab I have only pipeline script and there is no option to add any build steps here. My project is not free pipeline but there is a pipeline Syntax and I can add a Junit Publish Junit test result report.Once I clicked generate pipeline script I see `/ junit '.*Report'/`
 I want to add this to my unit console command to show junit report in jenkins.

Q1) What I am missing to show junit report in jenkins?
Q2) Is it mandatory to add Junit plugin in Pipeline tab to show report in jenkins--But I don't see those options in my jenkins & limitations to my current project.

```
stage('RUN UTEST')
bat""" cd project//Types//NUnit.Runners2.6.4//Commands 
nunit-console..//Tests/bin//Unit.dll /include:Unit /xml=Report.xml;[transform=nunit3-junit.xslt]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call junit in your pipeline

```
stage('RUN UTEST')
bat""" cd project//Types//NUnit.Runners2.6.4//Commands 
nunit-console..//Tests/bin//Unit.dll /include:Unit /xml=Report.xml;[transform=nunit3-junit.xslt]
"""
junit '**/Report.xml'
```

Comment: Script executed test case passed. I can see output pass/fail test cases & jenkins build successful but i dont see any published report.

Comment: Where is your report (path) and what's the file name?